# How do you store an ObjectId while using Doctrine MongoDB ODM?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, mongodb

I want to store references manually instead of letting the ODM use the DBRef type.

I have the option of storing the _id I want to reference as a @String (for e.g - "4e18e625c2749a260e000024" ), but how do I store an instance of an `ObjectId` in this field instead?

```
new \MongoId("4e18e625c2749a260e000024") <-- what's the annotation for this type?
```

Saving it using a MongoId object instead of a string will save me half the space on this field. It's the same data type used by the @Id annotation, but the @Id can be used just once in a Document.

What' the right annotation to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** There's now an official support for this type. Use `@ObjectId` or `@Field(type="object_id")` in your annotation to use the ObjectId / MongoId type. There's no need to use the solution below.

Also, use the latest master code from github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm and avoid using the version on the website (it's out-dated).

---

**Solution (deprecated)**

Looks like there's no support for this yet. I discussed this issue on the IRC channel and opened a ticket for it here: https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/125

A temporary fix would be to define a custom type and use an annotation like `@Field(type="objectid")` in your Document classes.

Here's the code for the custom type I'm using to accomplish this.

```
/**
 * Custom Data type to support the MongoId data type in fields
 */
class ObjectId extends \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Types\Type
{
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }
        if ( ! $value instanceof \MongoId) {
            $value = new \MongoId($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value)
    {
        return $value !== null ? (string)$value : null;
    }
}
```

Register it using

```
\Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Types\Type::addType('objectid', 'ObjectId' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/** @Id(strategy="NONE") */
```

Comment: I tried it. This doesn't work. It looks like you can use an @Id only once per document. Doesn't look like it supports this type. If I use this @Id with NONE strategy, then the primary identifier of the document stops working. Looks like it overrides behavior previously defined.